# Digest Auth - encoding of email address username

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, digest-authentication

I've made successful calls to a 3rd party API which uses Digest Authentication using Postman.

When I attempt to make the same request using an HttpClient, I'm getting "Unauthorized" back.

Using Fiddler to compare the request headers being sent up from Postman vs my code, I can see that my code is attempting to encode the username to UTF-8, but Postman doesn't.

Postman:

```
Digest username="user.name@email.com" {rest of the digest credentials}
```

Code:

```
Digest username*=utf-8''user.name%40email.com {rest of the digest credentials}
```

The realm, nonce, uri, response, algorithm, opaque, qop, nc & cnonce all match.

I've confirmed it's the "@" character causing the username to be wrapped in the encoding - but why would it be causing a problem and how do I get around it?